# C# create tor hidden service trough controlport

Tags: c#, tor

So I'm making a small chat application like ricochet, but then in C# and I succesfully connect to the tor controlport and create a hidden service id and private key, however after that point i got stuck, I send `ADD_ONION NEW:BEST Port=8946,127.0.0.1:8946\r\n` to the tor control port and it answers with hidden service id and private key and code 250. But what should I do to make it automatically run the service? I tried googling it but couldnt find anything and all examples are python or c++ if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. Also, im using Knapcode.TorSharp, so the tor installation is NOT persistent, the user has a profile file where the key etc are saved and it should start from there.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It does run automatically when you call `ADD_ONION`.  Are you asking how to make it start automatically in the future?

Comment: Ahh okay, and yes, like: the user has an account file, if it contains a private key and id already it should use those and otherwise create it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `ADD_ONION`, the hidden service starts running immediately (accessible once it can publish the Hidden Service descriptors and establish circuits [usually within a minute or two]).

If you want those services to start again automatically on subsequent runs (for a non-persisting Tor installation), then you'll need to programatically make similar calls to `ADD_ONION` when your application restarts and detects that private keys are saved to the profile.

You can re-create hidden services using existing keys with syntax like:

```
ADD_ONION RSA1024:*PKEY_GOES_HERE* Flags=DiscardPK Port=8946,8946
```

When you call `ADD_ONION` the first time, the response should look something like:

```
250-ServiceID=abcdefg123456
250-PrivateKey=RSA1024: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
250 OK
```

You'll want to save what it gave back in `PrivateKey`, and use this value to restart the hidden services the next time you run your application.

Comment: Happy to help :)